# react typescript image resizing and download

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I was implement image resize and image download.
But I see an error in 73line..

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-monad-sc6imu?file=/src/App.tsx

I see an reference, but I can't solve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, change the declaration of the `cardRef` to:

```
const cardRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

You should also remove the casting (`const card = cardRef.current as any;`) and modify it as follows:

```
const onDownloadBtn = () => {
    if(cardRef.current){
      const card = cardRef.current;
      domtoimage.toBlob(card).then((blob) => {
        saveAs(blob, "card.png");
      });
    } 
  };
```